# I want to consume login API (node.js) on my swift code using Alamofire

Tags: node.js, swift, alamofire

Im getting an error while im trying to login:
there's my login service, im sure it works so well because I tested it on postman, and I worked with it already on android, and it works perfectly, encrypted password and salt works so well ..

```
app.post('/login/',(req,res,next)=>{
    var post_data = req.body;

    //Extract email and password from request
    var user_password = post_data.password;
    var email = post_data.email;

    con.query('SELECT * FROM user where email=?',[email],function (err,result,fields) {
        con.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('[MYSQL ERROR]', err);
        });
        if (result && result.length)

        {
            var salt = result[0].salt;
            var encrypted_password = result[0].encrypted_password;
            var hashed_password = checkHashPassword(user_password, salt).passwordHash;
        if (encrypted_password == hashed_password)
            res.end(JSON.stringify(result[0]))
        else
            res.end(JSON.stringify('Wrong Password'))


        }

        else {

                res.json('user not exists!!');

            }

    });


})
```

and there's my swift code on btn_login action, im using Alamofire, he shows me an error with the url, but i worked with same url on displaying data from my table at it worked fine

```
    @IBAction func btn_login(_ sender: Any) {


        let serverUrl = "https://127.0.0.1:1337/login"


        guard let email = emailtf.text, !email.isEmpty else {return}
        guard let password = passwordtf.text, !password.isEmpty else {return}


      let loginRequest = [
                   "email" : email,
                   "password" : password
               ]

        Alamofire.request(serverUrl, method: .post, parameters: loginRequest, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .validate(statusCode:200..<300)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print(value)


                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error)

                        break
                    }
            }
    }
```

and im getting this error on xcode console

```
["Email": "test", "Password": "test"]
2019-11-23 15:41:19.991572+0100 ProjetIOS[19982:799169] Task <F5DB6B8F-2658-4C83-BF64-663B04673CAC>.<1> finished with error [-1002] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=localhost:1337/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=localhost:1337/login, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F5DB6B8F-2658-4C83-BF64-663B04673CAC>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F5DB6B8F-2658-4C83-BF64-663B04673CAC>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002f809f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}
Request failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=localhost:1337/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=localhost:1337/login, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F5DB6B8F-2658-4C83-BF64-663B04673CAC>.<1>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F5DB6B8F-2658-4C83-BF64-663B04673CAC>.<1>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002f809f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}
```

Any help please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

put your local IP instead of localhost in url .
e.g. http://192.168.1.34:1337/

Also try adding headers in your Alamofire request. Here is an example:

```
let loginRequest = [
        "Email" : self.emailtf.text! as String,
        "Password" : self.passwordtf.text! as String
    ]
let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]

Alamofire.request(url, method : .post, parameters : loginRequest, encoding : 
JSONEncoding.default , headers : headers).responseData { dataResponse in

 print(dataResponse.request as Any) // your request 
 print(dataResponse.response as Any) // your response
 }
```

Comment: yes i did it already but due to my login api, i always get "user not exist" even if i enter a valid user

Comment: try sending headers too in your alamofire network request.

Comment: im new on ios development, but i tried the code and it didn't work

Comment: I have updated my code on login_btn, check it, and i got this error now (Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.")

Comment: why using https? use http.. and in info.plist, allow arbitary loads like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/8374890

Comment: already done mate but still doesn't work and have the same problem